# Sensor data from Postgres to Redis

Tags: postgresql, change-data-capture, redis, tabular-data-stream

I have a Postgres database with a table that is updated with new data every 5 minutes from a weather station.

Now, as soon as the table is updated with a new record from the sensor, I would like this new record to be sent to a Redis Stream database.

Please note the following:

- Obviously, I could make the weather station sends data to both Postgres and Redis but this is not what I want.
- Using Kafka is not an option for my case (I would like to avoid Java).
- A delay of a few seconds (less than 5 seconds) would be acceptable.
- Probably a cron-job would be the easiest solution but I am looking for something more elegant if possible.

I am not an expert in Databases. I am just trying to understand what are some realistic options and how *change data capture* could work in my setting.

Comment: You can use [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding-example.html). You can pick or write [plugin](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logical_Decoding_Plugins) and stream your data to redis with that.

Comment: Is this the only other option you would suggest @Sahap Asci ?